# incompatible types required char found java.lang.string

Tags: java, string, compiler-errors, char

```
package com.Company;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        char myChar = "\u00A9";
    }
}
```

Comment: `"\u00A9"` is a String literal. You need `'\u00A9'`

Comment: You need to explain your problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're initializing the variable myChar as type char, but trying to fit a String inside. Java uses double quotes ("") for Strings and single quotes ('') for chars. To fix this is simple:

```
char myChar = '\u00A9';
```

The single quotes make ALL the difference!